# How to toggle visibility property (billboard.show) of a CZML entity's billboard?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

According to the Cesium API, to toggle the visibility of an asset's billboard (or label) you can simply assign the billboard.show property to false. When I attempted to do this, Cesium would error with

```
An error occurred while rendering.  Rendering has stopped.
TypeError: undefined is not a function
...
```

[This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cesium-dev/gATS8KL3fAw/2HxLzz86u4AJ) from the cesium-dev google group includes some example code to toggle billboard visibility on/off. The same code does not work if you attempt show = false on an entity from CZML (this example does not use CZML).

Here is what I tried

```
var asset = loadedCZML.entities.getById(id);
asset.billboard.show = false; //Error!
```

(loadedCZML is a `Cesium.CzmlDataSource`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doc's don't mention that the `show` property of your entity might not always be a simple boolean property (as the API describes).

When working with a `CzmlDataSource`'s `entity`, the `show` property is considered a `TimeIntervalCollectionProperty` (at least it was with my CZML).

All properties in Cesium must implement a `getValue` function, and when you go to set your `show = false`, the setter for the property is unable to apply false to a `TimeIntervalCollectionProperty` and instead replaces the entire property with a simple value of `false`.

The error `undefined is not a function` is a result of the cesium render call attempting to call getValue() on our `show` property. Regardless, the fix is simple:

Instead of this:

`asset.billboard.show = false; //error`

Do this:

```
asset.billboard.show = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(false);
```

PS: This applies for other Cesium properties, see the following example:

```
entity.billboard.image = pinBuilder.fromColor(Cesium.Color.CRIMSON, 48); //error

//do this instead
entity.billboard.image = new Cesium.ConstantProperty(pinBuilder.fromColor(Cesium.Color.CRIMSON, 48).toDataURL());
```